# Split-step-method for coupled equations

Tags: time-integration, operator-splitting

I have implemented a split-step-method for an equation of the shape 
$$\partial_z E = i\partial_x^2E+ic|E|^2E$$
resulting in a split into the linear part
$$L=\partial_x^2$$
and the nonlinear part
$$N=c|E|^2E$$
giving me
$$E(x, z+\Delta z)=\exp(i\Delta z(N+L))E(x, t)$$
But now my $c$-variable is non-constant, but rather 
$$\partial_tc=|E|^4$$
How do I couple that to my equation above in the split-step approach (either using an FFT or a DHT)? I can not include it as nonlinear term, after it does not depend on $E$, only on the absolute value.

Comment: Why not use a method whereby you first compute $E$ based on the previous $c$, and then compute $c$ based on the just-computed $E$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: I calculate $c$ after the initial linear step (I am using a $LNL$-method) using $c = |E|^4\cdot dt + c_0$, and use this value for calculating the nonlinear step. Is there a possible estimation about the error of that approach?

Comment: You are using a first-order operator splitting method for the coupled system. There are plenty of books about how to estimate the error.

Comment: I use a modified version of the code above, resulting in an error of $\Delta z^2$, but I was wondering how the error changes when I calculate $c$ in the middle of the half-step.